# What do these Bluetooth icons shown in iOS status bar mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, icon, speakers

I have two Bluetooth speakers from the same brand. They both have a mic and a call answer button as well as media playback control.

When I connect to one of them I see the following icon in the status bar:

[image: Bluetooth logo with battery]

The other speaker when connected, shows the following in the status bar:

[image: Headphones icon]

1. Why is a speaker represented by a headphones icon?
2. Why do the icons differ?
3. What are their respective meanings?
4. Does the absence of a battery indicator mean that the speaker doesn't report battery status?

I am using iOS 10.3.3.

Comment: What speaker is this? In the first one was it charging?

Comment: @DaniilManokhin It's the reseller's own brand: roxcore Aqua and roxcore Crossbeat, respectively. Yes, it was charging, but that detail makes no difference to the appearance of the icon.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the Apple Support document, [Status icons and symbols on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207354):

> [image]
>
> The battery level of your paired Bluetooth device.
>
> [image]
>
> Your iPhone is paired with a wireless headset, headphones, or earbuds.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect them to provide such a document. Do you happen to know why the icons differ? Are they using different Bluetooth profiles, or is the first one just used whenever the device reports remaining battery charge?

Comment: @Andreas The only publicly available info is what's shared in the linked document. I suspect the battery icon is shown by iOS whenever the device reports remaining charge.

Answer (score 0):

The first one shows the battery level if reported.

The second one is showing that a wireless headset or speakers are connected.

> Why is a speaker represented by an headphones icon?

That is the default icon for all audio connection.

> Why do the icons differ?

The first one is when the devices battery level, when not reported it wont show.

> What are their respective meanings?

The first tone is the device is charging. The second one that some speakers or a headset is connected.

> Does the absence of a battery indicator mean that the speaker doesn't report battery status?

Yes. To view the battery while the device battery is not displayed, there is a battery widget available when swiping right on the first page of the Home Screen.

Apple recommend answer:

> The icon is displayed if the device sends a signal to the iPhone to report the connection and battery status. That is something new for the iPhone. I agree with deggie that the icon is just a standard, they don't have different icons for different devices. It is just reporting the device connected and the battery status of the device.

([Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7813489?answerId=31241676022#31241676022))

Comment: Please see my reply to the question about charging in your comment

Comment: @Andreas hmm.. are you sure the device is charging/maybe it was fully charged

Comment: The device always has a battery indicator when connected, regardless of whether it's charging or not. This has been its behavior since purchase several months ago, AFAIR.

Comment: @Andreas if it is not showing then no charge is reported

Comment: @Andreas updated answer with an apple recommended quotation: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7813489?answerId=31241676022#31241676022