# Display the bluetooth headset and battery status icons in the iPhone status bar

Tags: iphone, battery, bluetooth, headphones, icon

**I would like to show in the iPhone status bar the bluetooth headset and battery status icons.** The icons provide an easy visual confirmation that the headset is connected/disconnected, and the visual measure of the amount of charge left in the headset battery.

They used to look like this:

[image: old iphone status bar ok]

Now they are missing:

[image: new iphone status bar not ok]

---

**Notes:**

- I have iPhone 15, running iOS 17.1.1.
- I am aware of this trick to show these icons: swipe from top right corner to show the control center, which shows the BT headset and battery icon (see below). But I need these icons to show on my home screen in the status bar.

[image: control center status bar ok]

- I am **not** asking: "Why did Apple design it this way?". I just want the easiest workaround for the missing icons.

**See also:**

- [What do these Bluetooth icons shown in iOS status bar mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/349339/329079)
- [How to find the iPhone status bar icons that Apple moved because of the notch | AppleInsider](https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/11/18/how-to-find-the-iphone-status-bar-icons-that-apple-moved-because-of-the-notch)
- [Status icons and symbols on your iPhone - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207354)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide a way to modify the system status bar at the time of writing.

A helpful workaround I've found useful is to display the battery status on the lock screen or home screen as a widget. Seeing the widget every time I go to unlock my phone seems to be sufficient for me to keep an eye on my earbuds battery:

[image: The batteries widget on the iOS lock screen]

After adding the widget, press on it again to reveal options to change the device shown on the widget.

A similar widget is available for the home screen too if that's more convenient:
[image: Preview of the batteries widget on the iOS home screen]

The batteries widget should work with any Bluetooth device that reports its battery status, not just connected Apple devices.

Comment: Helpful links: (a) [How to add and edit widgets on your iPhone - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207122), (b) [How do I get my battery widget back on my front screen - Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254117295), (c) [Show the iPhone battery percentage - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/show-the-battery-percentage-iph4747a74a9/ios)